# How do I get rid of the "ImpellerValidationBreak" error in my Flutter project?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, intellij-idea

I have the following problem in my Flutter project (IDE: IntelliJ). It only happens in my iOS simulator (iOS 17) and not in the Android simulator.

As soon as I click on a button which calls a menu (e.g. Upload Photo -> CupertinoActionSheet with 2 buttons) the screen in the simulator flickers for a while and I get the following error:

> [VERBOSE-2:validation.cc(49)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Could not create render pipeline: only 14 constant buffers binding are supported in the simulator but 17 were used
> [VERBOSE-2:validation.cc(49)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Failed to get or create runtime effect pipeline.
> [VERBOSE-2:validation.cc(49)] Break on 'ImpellerValidationBreak' to inspect point of failure: Failed to render entity.

I don't know what it is because I haven't installed any new packages or anything. The last weeks it worked normally.

I have already updated Flutter. Updated the IDE. Xcode is up to date, MacOS is up to date. Flutter doctor shows that everything is ok. Flutter clean, Flutter pub get, pod deintegrate, pod install I have tried everything several times. I just don't know the solution.

Comment: I think it's relative https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134852